# Creating hyperlink and renaming hyperlink display text

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word

I am trying to put together a Macro (VBA) that will transform text to a hyperlink in a word document.

I have the below VBA for it:

```
Sub ConvertURLTextsToHyperlinksInDoc()
  Dim objDoc As Document

  Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

  Word.Options.AutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks = True
  objDoc.Range.AutoFormat
End Sub
```

This is all good and it works, but I would also like for the specific hyperlink to have different display text. For example, the Word document contains `https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-windows-10?step=Win10Question1` not hyperliked, just plain text. I run the macro with the above VBA, and it creates a hyperlink. I need it to create a hyperlink and rename the display text to "Link". Currently with the above VBA I can only create a hyperlink with the current text.

Ideally, if i have for example links from two different websites, I would like them to be renamed to two different names, for example:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-windows-10?step=Win10Question1 to "Microsoft"
https://www.msn.com/en-us/sports to "MSN"

An add-in would be even better, but I can focus on Macro first.

Comment: VB.NET is to vba as *car* is to *carpet*.  please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I suggest you select such a hyperlink in a document and record a macro while using the `Insert\Link\Hyperlink` command in the Ribbon. That will give you the code you need for transforming and labeling.

Answer (score 0):

After your present code, you could insert:

```
Dim HLnk As Hyperlink, Rslt As Variant
For Each HLnk In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
  With HLnk
    .Range.Select
    Rslt = InputBox("Input the desired Hyperlink display text", "Edit Hyperlink Display", .TextToDisplay)
    If Rslt = "" Then
      Exit Sub
    Else
      .TextToDisplay = Rslt
    End If
  End With
Next
```

If you don't want to edit the display text interactively, Word would need some other way of identifying the required display text for each link. That might be hard-coded into your macro (making maintenance more of a chore) or by adding extra content immediately before or after the urls (e.g. «MSN»https://www.msn.com/en-us/sports) and modifying your code to look for such strings and apply what's between the «» as the .TextToDisplay.